# When can a function be taken inside a sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Consider a convergent sum of the form
$$ A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c\, a_n(x)\, x^n. $$
This sum is also bounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$, for example, it is a Taylor series for $A(x)$ at $0$.

I am interested in the product of $A(x)$ with $B(x)$, where $B(x)$ is bounded $\forall\, x$,
$$ B(x)A(x) = B(x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\, a_n(x)\, x^n. $$
I want to take $B(x)$ into the sum to get
$$ B(x)A(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\, B(x)\, a_n(x)\, x^n. $$
Under what conditions is this sum also guaranteed to converge, particularly as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Note that I know the product $B(x)\, a_n(x)\, x^n$ is bounded $\forall\,x$.

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85287/b-n-bounded-sum-a-n-converges-absolutely-then-sum-a-nb-n-also) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690285/question-about-convergence-of-sum-a-n-cdot-b-n-when-sum-a-n-converges?rq=1) which seem similar. Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I'm not sure if I can apply their answers to my situation. Can I simply use the fact that $c \sum_n a_n = \sum_n c\, a_n$ for bounded $c$? Or are there any special considerations, due to the fact that $B$ depends on $x$ which also occurs in the sum?

Also, does anything change if $B(x)$ is complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x$ you can always take $B(x)$ inside the sum. This does follow from the fact that $c \sum a_n =\sum ca_n$.  It is not clear what you mean by 'particularly as $ x \to \infty$'